# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, centos7, u-boot

I'm trying create an u-boot image file. But have i have some error.

```
gcc version: 7.3.0

make PATH=/opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/arm-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi:$PATH
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-(or arm-none-linux-gnueabi)
make ARCH=arm xilinx_zynq_defconfig
make -j ARCH=arm UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000 uImage
```

ERROR:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-mabi=aapcs-linux’
gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-mabi=’ are: ms sysv
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mlittle-endian’; did you mean ‘-fconvert=little-endian’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=vfp’; did you mean ‘-mcpu=’?
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
```

How can i fix? any idea?

Comment: I'm not a uboot expert but it looks like you are not correctly cross compiling but instead end up using the native toolchain. Probably haven't set `CROSS_COMPILE` env var.

Comment: I'm setting with this;
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
Edit my command now.

Comment: `make PATH=...` Is that really what you ran?

Comment: Yes.  i did try `export PATH=..` still same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more deterministic way of pointing to the exact toolchain you want to use is to provide its full prefix when setting `CROSS_COMPILE`. This will avoid possible path-related errors, and the information on which exact toolchain was used for building will be embedded in your build script.

Full example - installing official Arm gcc toolchain and retrieving/building u-boot 20.04 for xilinx_zynq_virt (use your own u-boot and defconfig):

```
# gcc 9.2.0
mkdir -p /opt/arm/9
wget 'https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz?revision=64186c5d-b471-4c97-a8f5-b1b300d6594a&la=en&hash=5E9204DA5AF0B055B5B0F50C53E185FAA10FF625'
tar Jxf gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz -C /opt/arm/9

# u-boot
wget https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/archive/v2020.04.tar.gz
tar zxf v2020.04.tar.gz
cd u-boot-2020.04
make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi- ARCH=arm mrproper xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig all
ll -gG u-boot*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 5778348 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot*
-rwxrwxr-x 1  599172 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot.bin*
-rw-rw-r-- 1   14907 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1    9181 Jun 19 08:09 u-boot.cfg.configs
-rwxrwxr-x 1  665132 Jun 19 08:09 u-boot.elf*
-rw-rw-r-- 1      70 Jun 19 08:09 u-boot-elf.lds
-rw-rw-r-- 1  599612 Jun 19 08:09 u-boot-elf.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1  599236 Jun 19 08:09 u-boot.img
-rw-rw-r-- 1    1626 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot.lds
-rw-rw-r-- 1  696711 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot.map
-rwxrwxr-x 1  599172 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot-nodtb.bin*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1797626 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot.srec*
-rw-rw-r-- 1  184969 Jun 19 08:08 u-boot.sym
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 5):

Your PATH is pointing to some 2011 GCC cross compiler. You need at least GCC 6 which was released in 2016. Please, install a current release of GCC.

On Debian or Ubuntu the C compiler for the host system and the cross compilers are separate packages. You can install the cross-compilers for 32bit and 64bit ARM with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

As the compilers are installed in /usr/bin it is sufficient to set the CROSS_COMPILER variable like

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

or

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

Comment: Thanks. i did install gcc-8,2 but i need change gcc path, i guess. Do u know how can i change gcc path ?

Comment: The host GCC and the GCC cross compiler are separate packages. For Ubuntu I have added a description above.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path you entered correct?.
I think you should add "/bin",so it'll be this way:

```
export PATH=/path
```

…to

```
<your toolchain>/bin:$PATH
```